# How to deactivate "update this field mapping" for users?

Tags: export

I would like the users to have only permissions for saving a new export mapping, and not updating the existing ones. Where can I modify this permissions?

Thank you!

Comment: Ok I take your comments into account. Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way afaik to do this currently. You might need to make an extension that adds field to the civicrm_mapping table that would then permit you to create a Permission that you can then apply.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Pete that there's no way to do what's being requested currently out of the box.  I'd probably take a different approach though, and change this at the form layer.  I'd make an extension that checked permissions, then removed the applicable "update this mapping" checkbox using `hook_civicrm_buildForm`.